# How to send a simple data by Ajax jQuery to views.py in Django?

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax, http-post

I want to send a simple data (a number) from home.html to a function in views.py by using Ajax jQuery. But it seems that the the function is not being called.

**home.html:**
I get the success response correctly. I see the tagID on the success notification. I want to see that in my views.py

```
...
function GetInfo(e){
                document.getElementById("test3").innerHTML = e.target.myCustomID;
                var tagID = e.target.myCustomID;

        $.ajax({
            url: 'Ajax1',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                'tagID': tagID,
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert ("Congrats! You sent some data: " + tagID);}
            ,
            error: function() {
                 alert ("Something went wrong");
             }
                })};
```

**views.py:**
I want to see that this function is called by the ajax. So if the command print ("AAAAAAAAAAAAA") works, I am happy!

```
...
@csrf_exempt
def Ajax1(request):
    print ("AAAAAAAAAAAAA")
    if request.is_ajax() and request.POST():
        print("BBBBBBBBBBBBB")
        TagID = request.POST.get('tagID', None)
    else:
        raise Http404
```

**my_app/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', views.home_map, name="home"),
    url(r'^ajax/$', views.Ajax1, name="Ajax")
]
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'', include('my_app.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'^ajax/$', Ajax1, name='Ajax')
]
```

would you please let me know what I am missing? thanks

**UPDATE**

Based on the kind suggestions, I made some changes. Still this is not working.

**views.py: **

```
def ajax1(request):
    TagIDD = request.POST['object_type']
    print("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", TagIDD)
    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == "POST":
        print("BBBBBBBBBBBBB")
        TagID = request.POST.get('tagID')
    else:
        raise Http404
    # TagID = request.POST('tagID')
    print ("Hello")
    print(TagID)

    response = {
        'TagID': TagID
    }
    return HttpResponse(response)
```

**home.html**

```
    function GetInfo(e){
                document.getElementById("test3").innerHTML = 
                 e.target.myCustomID;
                const tagID = e.target.myCustomID;

                $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "{{ 'ajax-view/' }}",

                        data: {
                        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
                        'tagID': tagID
                         },
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert ("Congrats! You sent some data: " + 
                                       tagID);}
                        ,
                        error: function() {
                              alert ("Something went wrong");}
                        })
                };

 </script>
```

**my_app\urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', views.home_map, name="home"),
    url('ajax-view/', views.ajax1, name='ajax-test-view')
]
```

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'', include('wrms01_map.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Still, it seems that the ajax is not calling the function "ajax1" in views.py. But I can see the success notification. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The URL given to the JS needs to be the URL in your `urls.py` file. Perhaps have a read through this to help you; https://djangocentral.com/django-ajax-with-jquery/

Comment: `... and request.method == 'POST':`

Comment: @markwalker_ thanks. I tried all the names and urls, like, url: "{% url 'Ajax' %}", but it doesn't make the app to print "AAAAA" it means that the function is not being called.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks, I put the print "AAAAAAA" before that to make sure that it is calling the Ajax1 function. But its not. I think the problem is maybe in the url.py or somewhere else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing the ajax call wrong. You have to pass the **EXACT URL** of your endpoint inside the url:''

What you have done is passing a string 'Ajax1' which inside your urls.py is no where to be found. In you urls.py you have 'ajax' as the url pattern and Ajax1 is your view function name.

Also what I observe inside your urls.py you have same patterns for 2 different view methods (this is a bad practise).

For now do this inside your ajax

```
$.ajax({
            url: "{%url 'Ajax'%}",  //This is the jinja template tag that will automatically fill in the url pattern from your urls.py corresponding to the name of that url pattern
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                'tagID': tagID,
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert ("Congrats! You sent some data: " + tagID);}
            ,
            error: function() {
                 alert ("Something went wrong");
             }
  })
```

Comment: Thanks Ruchit. I made an update on my question. will you please check that? thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, it seems that I had a mistake in urls.py

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home_map, name='home.html'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('ajax-view/', views.ajax1)
    # path('ajax/', ajax1, name='ajax1')
]
```

**home.html:**

```
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '{{ "ajax-view/" }}',

                        data: {
                        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
                        'tagID': tagID
                         },
                     success: function (data) {
                             alert ("Congrats! You sent some data: " 
                                    +tagID)
                    ,
                        error: function() {
                              alert ("Something went wrong");}
                        })
                };
```