# How to send a response from Django view function to a HTML popup windows

Tags: html, jquery, django

So, my app works like this:
1- user clicks and a function will call a ajax jquery send some data to a function in views.py, Done!
2- some process will be made in the function. some data are ready. Done!
3- I want to show the data on a html format like a popup window.

So, I am stuck in step 3.
I am new in this and I have not find any straight forward instruction.
You can find my step 1 in [How to send a simple data by Ajax jQuery to views.py in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68806893/how-to-send-a-simple-data-by-ajax-jquery-to-views-py-in-django)

Thanks in advance

Comment: please google your self and try to implement and raise if you find difficulty while implementing

Comment: Thanks @Println Actually I am googling for 2 days. I tried many thing. I am asking maybe I am missing a keyword or a method that I might not be heard of that.

Comment: out of the above mentioned 3 steps where are you facing the problem

Comment: Step 3 is my problem. Sorry I should mention more precisely.

Comment: this tutorial explains how to use modal popup windows  with django https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/15/how-to-implement-a-crud-using-ajax-and-json.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's almost as easy as any other view. Just return a render, and you can use django template syntax to process the context data.
You only need to write an ajax function (step 1) that creates a request,
A view that accepts it and returns data (step 2)
Inside the ajax success function from step 1 append the data to your HTML (or create a popup window)

Make sure to use dev tools if you are stuck in between step 2 and 3. If django returns data, you will be able to inspect it inside the form of an XHR response

```
# The HTML returned mainly consists of a javascript lib 
@login_required
def barcode_scan(request):
    # usually you would fill this page with some context data
    return render(request, "barcode.html")


# View for accepting ajax requests and for returning more data
@login_required
def barcode_view(request, tracking):
    shipment = get_object_or_404(PhysicalShipment, tracking_id=tracking)

    if request.method == "POST":

        if shipment.is_returnable():
            # ... some more logic here ...
            customer = shipment.customer
            content = shipment.content
            context = {
                "customer": customer,
                "content": content,
                # ...
                "canreturn": False,
            }
            return render(request, "barcode_snippet.html", context)
        else:
            success = False
            error_message = shipment.get_status_error_message()
            return JsonResponse({"success": success, "error": error_message})

    elif request.GET.get("ajax"):
        """ displays barcode shipment information """
        customer = shipment.customer
        content = shipment.content
        context = {
            "customer": customer,
            "content": content,
            # ...
            "canreturn": shipment.is_returnable(),
        }
        return render(request, "barcode_snippet.html", context)

    return render(request, "barcode.html")
```

In my example, barcode.html contains a js-barcodescanner. After detecting a code it will call the view the GET parameter ?ajax=True and with the tracking_code. The server will respond with a barcode_snippet, it contains context data about the content and the customer. Based on the flag canreturn the user will be able to click a Link inside the details window, this time it will POST the data, which will then trigger some server side things.
Again, the barcode_snippet is returned, this time the action is forbidden.

I then use JQuery to attach the response (barcode_snippets) to my site.

```
success: function (response) {
    $("#results").append(response);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I used your suggestions in my app. It works!. Actually, I couldn't get the popup windows, but I was successful in getting the data in the main html that is ok for me. Thanks again